# How to move caption for a Tikz node?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using [this](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/signal-flow-building-blocks/) library to create a signal flow graph. To test this please include [this package](https://github.com/kitmonisit/signalflow), which is an updated version of the library, in the folder and exchange enter the path of `signalflowgraph.sty` in `\usepackage{signalflowgraph}`

I want to move the caption of the node. For simple up, down, left, right motions it seems to be sufficient to use \nodepart, but from what I understand this actually parts the node in two. What I want to do is move the caption to "above right" or "northwest and couldn't make it so far. What I am achieving to do is move the caption of n2 to northwest and move the caption of n1 a little higher. I have tried changing it to

```
    \node[node, label={[above right]:$x_h[n-1]$}] (n2)
    {}; &&
```

but that messes up the whole graphic.

Here is my code

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,            
  DIV=10,             
  oneside,           
  BCOR=5mm,           
  parskip=half,       
  numbers=noenddot,  
  bibtotoc,          
  listof=totoc        
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{signalflowdiagram}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [every node/.style={anchor=center}]
  \matrix (m) [minimum width=6in,
    row sep=10mm,
    column sep=10mm]
  {%
    % row 1
    \node[input] (in)
    {$x[n]$}; &
    \node[adder] (a1)
    {}; &&&
    \node[node] (n1)
    {\nodepart{above}{$x_h[n]$}}; &&
    \node[multiplier] (m1)
    {\nodepart{above}{-c}}; &
    \node[adder] (a2)
    {}; &
    \node[output] (out)
    {$y[n]$}; \\ &&&&

    % row 2
    \node[delay] (d1)
    {$z^{-1}$}; \\ &

    % row 3
    \node[adder] (a3)
    {}; &
    \node[multiplier] (m2)
    {\nodepart{above}{-d(1-c)}}; &&
    \node[node] (n2)
    {\nodepart{above}{$x_h[n-1]$}}; &&
    \node[multiplier] (m3)
    {\nodepart{above}{d(1-c)}}; &
    \node[adder] (a4)
    {}; \\ &&&&

    % row 4
    \node[delay=west] (delay2)
    {$z^{-2}$}; \\ &&

    % row 5
    \node[multiplier] (m4)
    {\nodepart{above}{c}}; &&
    \node[node] (n3)
    {\nodepart{below}{$x_h[n-2]$}}; &
        \\
  };

  \path[r>] (in) -- (a1);
  \path[r>] (a1) -- (n1);
  \path[r>] (n1) -- (m1);
  \path[r>] (m1) -- (a2);
  \path[r>] (a2) -- (out);

  \path[r>] (n1) -- (d1);
  \path[r>] (d1) -- (n2);
  \path[r>] (n2) -- (delay2);
  \path[r>] (delay2) -- (n3);

  \path[r>] (n2) -- (m2);
  \path[r>] (m2) -- (a3);
  \path[r>] (n2) -- (m3);
  \path[r>] (m3) -- (a4);

  \path[r>] (n3) -- (m4);
  \path[r>] (m4) -| (a3);
  \path[r>] (n3) -| (a4);
  \path[r>] (a4) -- (a2);
  \path[r>] (a3) -- (a1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and the image

[image]

Comment: Can you please extend your code to a full MWE (from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`?

Comment: Does this play a role? I have so many libraries included that it would be tedious and clogging the code. My only issue is with the tikz image. I added the relevant libraries. Hoping it is okay now.

Comment: The expected standard for a question on this site is to contain a fully self-contained, copy&paste-compilable piece of LaTeX code. This makes it easier for all participants to replicate your current state and to know all the boundary conditions (e.g. is this actually a slide in `beamer`, or some journal or poster class). You were right in only including the packages relevant for this image. You probably could even shave off most of the tikzlibraries. See it this way: the easier it is for someone to compile your document, the faster you get an answer.

Comment: Okay, I just tested it and the current version definitely compiles. Hoping someone can help me as I have to turn this in on Wednesday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow/scan/search the official tutorials for such common problems, in your case [Diagrams as simple graphs](http://ctan.ebinger.cc/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page=70) shows *one* possible approach to solve your task:

Just add additional nodes with relative positioning that hold your caption. That decouples labelling from the rigid structure of the line matrix. Tikzlibrary `positioning` provides the helpful `above right=of <node-name>` notation, and together with specifying `node distance=<x>mm and <dy>mm` I get consistent spacing throughout. Applied to your n1, n2 and n3 this yields:

[image: signal flow graph with fixed label positions (no longer colliding with central node)]

Code

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,            
  DIV=10,             
  oneside,           
  BCOR=5mm,           
  parskip=half,       
  numbers=noenddot,  
  bibtotoc,          
  listof=totoc        
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{signalflowdiagram}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [every node/.style={anchor=center},
   node distance=1mm and 1mm]
  \matrix (m) [
    minimum width=6in,
    row sep=10mm,
    column sep=10mm]
  {%
    % row 1
    \node[input] (in)
    {$x[n]$}; &
    \node[adder] (a1)
    {}; &&&
    \node[node] (n1) {}; &&
    \node[multiplier] (m1)
    {\nodepart{above}{-c}}; &
    \node[adder] (a2)
    {}; &
    \node[output] (out)
    {$y[n]$}; \\ &&&&

    % row 2
    \node[delay] (d1)
    {$z^{-1}$}; \\ &

    % row 3
    \node[adder] (a3)
    {}; &
    \node[multiplier] (m2)
    {\nodepart{above}{-d(1-c)}}; &&
    \node[node] (n2)
    {\nodepart{above}{}}; &&
    \node[multiplier] (m3)
    {\nodepart{above}{d(1-c)}}; &
    \node[adder] (a4)
    {}; \\ &&&&

    % row 4
    \node[delay=west] (delay2)
    {$z^{-2}$}; \\ &&

    % row 5
    \node[multiplier] (m4)
    {\nodepart{above}{c}}; &&
    \node[node] (n3) {}; &
        \\
  };

  \path[r>] (in) -- (a1);
  \path[r>] (a1) -- (n1);
  \path[r>] (n1) -- (m1);
  \path[r>] (m1) -- (a2);
  \path[r>] (a2) -- (out);

  \path[r>] (n1) -- (d1);
  \path[r>] (d1) -- (n2);
  \path[r>] (n2) -- (delay2);
  \path[r>] (delay2) -- (n3);

  \path[r>] (n2) -- (m2);
  \path[r>] (m2) -- (a3);
  \path[r>] (n2) -- (m3);
  \path[r>] (m3) -- (a4);

  \path[r>] (n3) -- (m4);
  \path[r>] (m4) -| (a3);
  \path[r>] (n3) -| (a4);
  \path[r>] (a4) -- (a2);
  \path[r>] (a3) -- (a1);
  
  \node[above=of n1] (n1caption) {$x_h[n]$};
  \node[above right=of n2] (n2caption) {$x_h[n-1]$};
  \node[below=of n3] (n3caption) {$x_h[n-2]$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The graph may benefit from this spacing for your other multipliers (`c`, `-c` etc.) as well.

Comment: Thanks! I also wanted to convert the multipliers to a bigger icon with an x inside, but like that it would cover the caption. By looking at your graph I realized that the second delay is too long, but this is not related to Latex :)

Comment: Oh and I searched for some similar examples but was feeling I was lacking the basic understanding of tikz. When I have time, I will have a look at a tutorial. It is great what you can do with it

Comment: I won't spoil it, but the/one possible answer to your "multiplier as symbol with text inside" is in the same linked manual, section "5.1 Styling the Nodes". Happy tikzing!

Comment: Yeah but I am super stressed out and not focused. Half a year of working every day gets to you.